# To determine a fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, farey-sequences

How to calculate the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with $0<b\leq  7,$ such that $\vert \sqrt 3-\frac{a}{b}\vert\leq \frac{1}{8b}$

Comment: $\dfrac ab=\dfrac 74$

Comment: Yeah, I think $7/4$ is the only solution.

Comment: It's $1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+1}}$

Comment: How $\frac{7}{4}$??

Comment: I think $\frac{12}7$ also satisfies the inequality

Comment: That's $1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{1+1}}}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner will you please put your solution in Answer section rather then in comment?? But with solution.

Answer (score 2):

Truncated continued fractions provide good rational approximations.

The continued fraction for $\sqrt3$ is $1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{1+...}}}}},$

so good rational approximations to $\sqrt3$ are

$1, 1+1, 1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac12}, \color{blue}{1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+1}}}, \color{purple}{1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{2+\dfrac1{1+1}}}}$, etc.

It can be seen that $\color{blue}{\dfrac74}$ and $\color{purple}{\dfrac{12}7}$ are good enough rational approximations to meet the desired criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $b$ throughout we get
$$
\left| b\sqrt{3} - a \right| \le \frac18 \iff -\frac18 \le b\sqrt{3} - a \le \frac18
$$
Can you finish this now?

Comment: So will you please goe bit further in your poof to eliminate values of constant??